# Custom component doesn't display in one of my project in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, custom-controls

I have created a component to display and select multiple folders. I add it to the toolbox and it work perfectly in other projects but not in the project where i need it (not displayed)...

If i add it manually i have a reference broken message.

Intellisense find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to Upgrade to framework 4.5 my project. Now my component is avaible.